# How to fix syntax error in UPDATE statment in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to build a database and ran into a problem with the syntax in an UPDATE statement. Does anyone know what's wrong with the statement?

I've tried adjusting the use of single and double quotes but it's still not working.

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_SponsorContacts (ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, SponsorID )" _
    & " VALUES ('" & Me.txtContactName & "','" & Me.txtContactEmail & "', '" & Me.txtContactPhone & "' , '" & Me.txtSpnID & "')"
    Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_SponsorContacts SET ContactName = " _
    & " '" & Me.txtContactName & "', ContactEmail = '" & Me.txtContactEmail & "', " _
    & " ContactPhone = '" & Me.txtContactPhone & "', SponsorID = '" & Me.txtSpnID & "', WHERE ContactID = '" & Me.txtContactID & "'"
    End If
    Exit Sub
```

I keep getting the 3144 syntax error which doesn't provide any hints as to the cause. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to Jerry M. and forpas for suggesting to remove the comma before where. That helped but I am not getting an error 3061, "Too few parameters. Expected 1". 
I will post a new question.

Comment: Remove the `,` before WHERE

Comment: Don't just edit your question to reflect something new. Keep your original question and post a new one. This leads to inaccurate answers and confusing results for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @forpas mentioned in the comments, it looks like you have an extra `,`

Try below:

````
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_SponsorContacts (ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, SponsorID )" _
& " VALUES ('" & Me.txtContactName & "','" & Me.txtContactEmail & "', '" & Me.txtContactPhone & "' , '" & Me.txtSpnID & "')"
Else
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_SponsorContacts SET ContactName = " _
& " '" & Me.txtContactName & "', ContactEmail = '" & Me.txtContactEmail & "', " _
& " ContactPhone = '" & Me.txtContactPhone & "', SponsorID = '" & Me.txtSpnID & "'WHERE ContactID = '" & Me.txtContactID & "'"
End If
Exit Sub ```
````

Comment: Oh, I just noticed @forpas posted as a comment.

Comment: Thank you Jerry and @forpas. That got me a step closer but now I am getting an error 3061 "Too Few Parameters. Expected 1" Is that coming from the WHERE statement?

Comment: That is a different issue. That is probably relating to your `INSERT INTO` statement. I would suggest accepting an answer for this, and reopening a new question so that future users can explicitly target that problem =)